# kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB is deprecated on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, image, colors, core-graphics

I'm trying to get bitmap context with the following code:

```
GContextRef MyCreateBitmapContext (int pixelsWide, int pixelsHigh)
{
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);                          // 1
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);// 2
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );                          // 3
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        return NULL;
    }

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,                     // 4
                                    pixelsWide,
                                    pixelsHigh,
                                    8,      // bits per component
                                    bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpace,
                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    if (context== NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);                                          // 5
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );                              // 6
    return context;                                                 // 7
}
```

A warning says:`'kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB' is deprecated.`

Does this mean that `colorSpace` is unchangeable?  If that is true, we'll be unable to change the color data of any images using `colorSpace`. And how to process image then?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The generic color space is deprecated. Instead try;

`CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()`;