# Core Graphics - What is the appropriate way to create an RGB colorspace?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics

[Apple Says:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_color/dq_color.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH205-TPXREF101)
"If your application runs in iOS or in Mac OS X v10.4 and later, you can use device-independent color spaces or generic color spaces."

So that means I am to use CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(...) and not CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(...) because the latter is deprecated.  However, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560254/kcgcolorspacegenericrgb-is-deprecated-on-iphone) post on stackoverflow, it's said that the generic color space is deprecated.  What's the right answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGColorSpaceCreateWithName()` is the recommended function on MacOS, but `kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB` isn't available on iOS, so you have to use `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` instead (and isn't deprecated on that platform).